# Dockerize sample dotnet core exe application to kubernetes in linux pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I'm trying to create a dotnet core application and deploy it to a kubernetes cluster through azure yaml pipelines (with multiple repositories)
I'm hitting the following error:
CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/File.Pod/File.Pod.csproj]

The project was created with this command : dotnet new console -o File.Pod-n File.Pod
My Goal is to deploy an exe. Most of documentations on Internet talks about deployment ASPNET web applications.

csproj generated

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    **<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>**
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>  
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Models" Version="9704.0.0-beta" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Utils.Log" Version="2020.9.3.1" />
 </ItemGroup>  
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared.Lib\File.Service\File.Service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["File.Pod.csproj", "File.Pod/"]
COPY ["Shared.Lib/File.Service/File.Service.csproj", "Shared.Lib/File.Service/"]
COPY ["Shared.Lib/File.DAL/File.DAL.csproj", "Shared.Lib/File.DAL/"]

COPY ["nuget.config", "./"] 
RUN dotnet restore "File.Pod/File.Pod.csproj" --configfile nuget.config -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503 --verbosity diag
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/File.Pod"
RUN dotnet build "File.Pod.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "File.Pod.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS base
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-client
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

As ENTRYPOINT, I tried ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"] or ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "File.POD.DLL"] with no difference.

I feel that the problem is with the type of images ( FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build) , but I'm unsure. I tried various ones with same result.

Exact error log:
2020-09-11T11:05:41.9723837Z Step 10/26 : RUN dotnet build "File.Pod.csproj" -c Release -o /app
2020-09-11T11:05:42.0083655Z  ---> Running in 7ed9311b9c89
2020-09-11T11:05:42.7118936Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
2020-09-11T11:05:42.7119408Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2020-09-11T11:05:42.7119642Z
2020-09-11T11:05:43.1438745Z   Determining projects to restore...
2020-09-11T11:05:45.6330496Z   Restored /src/File.Pod/File.Pod.csproj (in 2.04 sec).
2020-09-11T11:05:45.6330978Z   Restored /src/Shared.Lib/File.Service/File.Service.csproj (in 2.05 sec).
2020-09-11T11:05:45.7516552Z   Restored /src/Shared.Lib/File.DAL/File.DAL.csproj (in 101 ms).
2020-09-11T11:05:49.6118355Z   File.DAL -> /app/File.DAL.dll
2020-09-11T11:05:50.2378452Z   File.Service -> /app/File.Service.dll
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6394251Z CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/File.Pod/File.Pod.csproj]
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6525494Z
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6525914Z Build FAILED.
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6531013Z
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6536286Z CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/File.Pod/File.Pod.csproj]
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6541921Z     0 Warning(s)
2020-09-11T11:05:50.6542199Z     1 Error(s)

Answer (score 1):

8 hours of work and 47 build attempts later:

Changed :

```
COPY . .  
WORKDIR "/src/File.Pod"
```

to

```
WORKDIR "/src/File.Pod"  
COPY . .
```

Note : There are tons of docs, but not an exhaustive good one.
I would expect one doc somewhere that would give sufficient knowledge to get started correctly: choice of image, the directory scope, the importance of what to copy (who is able to understand the importance of "COPY . ." that copies the source code to avoid this error, etc...

I started 2 days ago with docker, vsts pipeline, multiple repositories and can already write a book with all the (weird,generic and obscure) errors I hitted.Not talking about the next step now in error, the problems to install docker in windows 2019 (in a VM hosted in Amazon), linux images that do not work (by default?) on the windows 2019 env.
What a nightmare, I wonder what is mature, hitted more problems these past 2 days than over the last decade ! :-)